# How many max python 24/7 request scripts i can run on gcloud tmux console

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, virtual-machine, instance

I have created a python script that has requests api to run 24/7 and i have hosted it on google cloud.

The task is about getting stock price change ticks every second via a python script api.

As i am newbie i am able to run that script on google cloud single instance for 24/7 but now i want to run like a 100 scripts simultaneously on t-mux and I don’t know which google cloud instance specification i can use or what is the maximum number of scripts t-mux can run or is there any other way to do this?

I have tried using multiple instances but that is costing too much so i was hoping if i can use just a single instances for all as all scripts are the same for different connections.

Any Help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You have given zero details about the task. How should we give any advice? Also choosing the right server product is not a software development topic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the project is about getting stock market tick data every second from an api.

Comment: You can use threads.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think differently. The question you want to ask is "How many outgoing connections can I make, and what the total size limit?"

Rephrasing it like that and reading the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_instance), it states:

- no more than 20 Gbps
- no more than 1,800,000 packets per second

It seems that it can support 100 scripts easily.